# Trying to submit two functions using onsubmit on a sign up form(have looked at other questions but no luck)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, onsubmit

I am only able to submit either get_action() or checkMandatory() separately. Trying to do both isnt working. In order to use get_action i have to use onClick and to use checkMandatory I have to use onsubmit. When i combine the two using onClick only get_action works. When i try to submit both using onsubmit only checkMandatory works.

The code below only fires CheckMandatory.

Please can someone help me reword the code so they both fire when someone clicks on the submit button?

I would like checkMandatory to fire first followed by get_action which will direct them to the right place based on their form options.

```js
Mailcheck.defaultDomains.push('hp.com', 'yahoo.com.tw', 'yahoo.com.au', 'yahoo.com.mx', 'seznam.cz', 'bellsouth.net', 'hotmail.fr', 'mail.ru', 'btinternet.com', 'cox.net', 'yahoo.com.br', 'bigpond.com', 'yahoo.fr', 'ymail.com', 'earthlink.net', 'xtra.co.nz', 'me.com', 'yahoo.gr', 'walla.com', 'yahoo.es', 'charter.net', 'shaw.ca', 'live.nl', 'yahoo.ca', 'orange.fr', 'optonline.net', 'gmx.de', 'wanadoo.fr', 'optusnet.com.au', 'rogers.com', 'web.de', 'ntlworld.com', 'juno.com', 'yahoo.com.sg', 'rocketmail.com', 'yandex.ru', 'yahoo.co.in', 'centrum.cz', 'live.co.uk', 'sympatico.ca', 'libero.it', 'walla.co.il', 'bigpond.net.au', 'yahoo.com.hk', 'ig.com.br', 'live.com.au', 'free.fr', 'sky.com', 'uol.com.br', 'abv.bg', 'live.fr', 'terra.com.br', 'hotmail.it', 'tiscali.co.uk', 'rediffmail.com', 'aim.com', 'blueyonder.co.uk', 'telus.net', 'bol.com.br', 'hotmail.es', 'email.cz', 'windowslive.com', 'talktalk.net', 'home.nl', 't-online.de', 'yahoo.de', 'telenet.be', '163.com', 'embarqmail.com', 'windstream.net', 'roadrunner.com', 'bluewin.ch', 'skynet.be', 'laposte.net', 'yahoo.it', 'qq.com', 'live.dk', 'planet.nl', 'hetnet.nl', 'gmx.net', 'mindspring.com', 'rambler.ru', 'iinet.net.au', 'eircom.net', 'yahoo.com.ar', 'wp.pl', 'mail.com', 'emmis.com', 'hotmail.de', 'lireo.com', 'gmx.at', 'ukr.net', 'zol.co.zw');
Mailcheck.defaultTopLevelDomains.push('com.au', 'com.br', 'ru', 'us')

function updateConditionals() {
  if (parent.$('#signupFormIframe3')) {
    parent.$('#signupFormIframe3').height($('body').height() + 20);
  }
}

function checkMandatory() {
  var ok2submit = 1;
  var errorFields = '';
  var atTest = /\@/;
  var dotTest = /\./;
  if ((atTest.test(document.signupForm.Email.value) == false) || (dotTest.test(document.signupForm.Email.value) == false)) {
    ok2submit = 0;
    errorFields += 'Email';
  }
  if (document.signupForm.User5.value == '') {
    ok2submit = 0;
    errorFields += ', Please select the closest city to where you live from the list';
  }
  if (document.signupForm.Lastname.value == '') {
    ok2submit = 0;
    errorFields += ', Lastname';
  }
  if (document.signupForm.Firstname.value == '') {
    ok2submit = 0;
    errorFields += ', Firstname';
  }
  if (document.signupForm.User8.value == '') {
    ok2submit = 0;
    errorFields += ', Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?';
  }
  if (ok2submit == 0) {
    var errorFields2 = errorFields.replace(/^\, /, '');
    alert('To submit this form, please ensure you have entered information for: ' + errorFields2);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#signup_Email').on('blur', function() {
    $('#emailEntryAlert').html('');
    $(this).mailcheck({
      suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
        $('#emailEntryAlert').html('Did you mean <a onclick="$(\'#signup_Email\').val(\'' + suggestion.full + '\'); $(\'#emailEntryAlert\').html(\'\');" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;" title="Click here to make this your intended email address">' + suggestion.full + '</a>?');
      },
      empty: function(element) {
        if ($('#signup_Email').val() == '') {
          $('#emailEntryAlert').html('Be sure to enter a valid email address!');
        }
      }
    });
  });
  $(':input').on('click', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $(':input').on('blur', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $(':input').on('focus', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $(':input').on('keyup', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('textarea').on('click', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('textarea').on('blur', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('textarea').on('focus', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('select').on('click', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('select').on('blur', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('select').on('focus', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    updateConditionals()
  });
  updateConditionals();
});

function get_action() {
  var optn_value = document.getElementById("signup_User5").value;
  var option_value = document.getElementById("signup_User8").value;
  if ((option_value == "Workshop Only") && (optn_value == "London")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuklondonworkshop.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Workshop Only") && (optn_value == "Birmingham")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukbirminghamworkshop.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Workshop Only") && (optn_value == "Manchester")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukmanchesterworkshop.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Audition Only") && (optn_value == "London")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Audition Only") && (optn_value == "Birmingham")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Audition Only") && (optn_value == "Manchester")) {
    document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value == "London")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value == "Birmingham")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation.html";
  } else if ((option_value == "Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value == "Manchester")) {
    window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation.html";
  }

}


function DoAllThese() {
  var retvalue;
  retvalue = checkMandatory();
  if (retvalue == false) {
    return retvalue;
  }
  retvalue = get_action();
}
```

```css
body,
input,
select,
label,
li,
p,
div,
span {
  font-family: arial;
}
.formRow label {
  font-size: 16px;
}
#labelFullName {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://app.greenrope.com/styles/signup.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://app.greenrope.com/img/joinback/design10.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/scripts/signup.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/mailcheck.min.js">
  </script>
  <title>Form
  </title>
  <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://app.greenrope.com/users/myteam4/Media1884.ico" />
  <link rel="icon" href="http://app.greenrope.com/users/myteam4/Media1884.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="logoDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="formTop">
    </div>
    <div id="formContainer">
      <form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" target="_top" method="post" action="http://app.greenrope.com/j1.pl?9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739" onsubmit="return DoAllThese();">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <ul id="teamFields">
                  <li class="formRow" id="field_Firstname">
                    <label class="fieldName" id="labelFirstname" for="signup_Firstname">First Name<span class="reqMarker">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="Firstname" value="" maxlength="64" id="signup_Firstname" class="inputTextField" />
                  </li>
                  <li class="formRow" id="field_Lastname">
                    <label class="fieldName" id="labelLastname" for="signup_Lastname">Last Name<span class="reqMarker">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="" maxlength="64" id="signup_Lastname" class="inputTextField" />
                  </li>
                  <li class="formRow emailRow" id="field_Email">
                    <label class="fieldName" for="signup_Email">Email<span class="reqMarker">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="64" value="" id="signup_Email" class="inputTextField" />
                    <div id="emailEntryAlert">
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User5">
                    <label class="fieldName" id="labelUser5" for="signup_User5">Please select the closest city to where you live from the list<span class="reqMarker">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select name="User5" id="signup_User5">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      <option value="London">London</option>
                      <option value="Birmingham">Birmingham</option>
                      <option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                  <li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User8">
                    <label class="fieldName" id="labelUser8" for="signup_User8">Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?<span class="reqMarker">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select name="User8" id="signup_User8">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      <option value="Workshop Only">Workshop Only</option>
                      <option value="Workshop + Audition">Workshop + Audition</option>
                      <option value="Audition Only">Audition Only</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="teamSelection">
                  <li class="formRow joinRow"><span id="confirmText"> </span>
                  </li>
                  <input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="4" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="3" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="1" />
                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="reqInfo">* required information
        </div>
        <input id="formSubmit" type="submit" name="formSubmit" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 8px !important; border-color: #d3d3d3 !important; border-radius: 0px !important; padding: 16px !important; background: #a9a9a9 !important; box-shadow: none !important;"
        value="Sign Me Up" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Referrer" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="qstring" value="9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739" />
        <input type="hidden" name="formSubmitCheck" value="1" />
      </form>
      <div id="formBottom">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you format your code so that it's readable, you might get a response.

Comment: RobG is right. You don't need to bring the entire code here. Ask the question clearly with the effective place in the code so that others can see it and give you the solution.

Comment: Why not simply call one function at the end of the other